# Why does curl in PHP display a 1 in the URL that I grab?

Tags: php, curl

I have written two files, an HTML file and a PHP file. I used in my PHP file the `curl` function, which I used to take the source code of my HTML file.

Here is the code:

HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pagina Youtube</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <label for="valore_youtube">Inserisci il nome del video:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="valore_youtube" id="valore_youtube">
        <input type="submit" value="INVIA" name="INVIA">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP file:

```
<?php
    $curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost/test/ilphp.html");
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
    $html = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);
    echo $html;
?>
```

The code shows the HTML file. But shows also an incomprehensible 1 in more as output, someone can help me?

Comment: To insert code here, paste it in, select it, and click the 'code' button. It will add the MarkDown indentation to render it correctly. There is formatting help available in the editor, please do read it!

Answer (score 4):

`curl_exec` outputs directly and then returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the call worked. This is rendered as `1` or `0` when you output it as a string.

You need to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` for `curl_exec` to return the HTML itself.

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```